# Change Empathy's status icons

Tags: icons, empathy

I installed a new icon theme but I want to use custom Empathy's status icons. I go to usr/share/empathy/hicolor & replace the icons there but it doesn't take effect ! Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace files in theme folder -/usr/share/icons/

A better idea would be creating a custom theme, which inherits original theme, but contains modified icons. [Here](http://stuffidowithubuntu.blogspot.com/2010/12/replacing-selctive-icons-in-ubuntumint.html) is a tutorial

Comment: The first tip didn't work for me but the link you provided is awesome :) thank you.